# Mac Xcode Zlib Linker Errors

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, zlib

I could use some help.  I am just getting into Mac development a bit.  This is a port from Windows and I am so close to finishing.  I am trying to link to ZLib as I have an application that depends on it.  I am creating multiple libraries with a fairly simple hierarchy.  Anyways, the important thing is, I am getting linker errors when trying to link to ZLib.  I have added libz.dylib as a framework and set it to the correct target but my calls to ZLib are getting "Symbol(s) not found" errors.  I have tried using the Z_PREFIX flag but no luck.  I have set the path of zlib to my library search paths even though I don't think I need it (/usr/lib..but it has an absolute path I think).  It shows up in my target as a link binary and its listed at the top of the list which makes me think that link order is not the issue.  The only header I link to is zlib.h and I even included that to the same target.  However, no matter what I try I still get the same error.  I was curious if anyone has any ideas.

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks much.

Erik

Comment: Hey Derek, thanks for the response.

Comment: Hey Derek, thanks for the response.  '_z_inflate, referenced from:' and the same for _z_inflateEnd, _z_InflateInit, _z_deflate, z_deflateInit, z_deflateEnd....My calls seemed to be mangled in the error output.  for inflate I call 'inflate(arg1, arg2)'.  It just isn't picking up anything and it is actually an open source library used in a 3d modelling platform.  So, I didn't write the interface.  I just need to put all the pieces together and I know it has been done before.  Not sure what other information would help but if you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I shouldn't have to update the source.  I'd be very surprised if I did.  Just seems that it can't pick up zlib for some reason.  My zlib header and lib are the ones shipped with the mac in the system frameworks.  I also verified that the version of zlib I need is the correct one I am have in my project.  I'm not sure how often they get updated anyway but it seems like it stays pretty constant.  Its not that my arguments are bad, just that it doesn't know what the symbols are.

Comment: Or maybe the Z_PREFIX is somehow defined somehwere??  Looking and looking...this is going down today.

Comment: Wooooowwww....Fixed it...Z_PREFIX was secretly being defined in the open source files I had...I don't think they were before so I am a little confused/worried working down the line but for now I am going to give myself a small pat on the back.  Library built.  That did it for me.  Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: @Erik You should add your final comment as an answer to your question. Not all comments are shown when the page first loads. I had to click through to find that you had answered your question in the comments. If you make an answer, then it will be a lot more helpful to future seekers who would like to benefit from your experience.